# python/appjar how to get selected text

Tags: python

I have created an application using Tkinter and am trying to re-implement it using AppJar. I am able to get the selected text from a textbox using

```
textWidget.get (Tkinter.SEL_FIRST,Tkinter.SEL_LAST)
```

I can't find any information on how to do this with AppJar, althought there is a list of tag related functions and mention of a "sel" tag. I've tried as many permutations as I can think of and nothing has worked.

I am sure it is very simple.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Randy

Answer (score 0):

It is simple :)

Have a look here: http://appjar.info/inputWidgets/#get-textareas

```
app.getTextArea('title')
```